# Non-existing picture appearing on table of contents

Tags: ms-word

I'm having a problem with a Microsoft Word document. My document has at least 60 pictures that's why I have a table of contents for all those pictures. Recently I have replaced one of the images and now the table of contents is showing a reference to a picture that does not exist in the document. I can't find it anywhere.

[image]

This is what is happening. I have a reference to a Figure 11 that does not exist. I've already updated the entire document references and still no luck. I've also hold the Ctrl button and clicked on the reference which leads to nowhere. Just for the record, I have the track changes setting on.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I've realized that this problem was realated to the Track Changes setting being on. Since MS Word was keeping track of all changes, when removing a picture you need to **Right Click** the area where that removal happened and press **Accept Removal**.